# Installing older iOS for device testing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

It used to be simpler to test versions of the iOS that were older than the currently shipping iOS.  I can't seem to find a way to do it now that Apple calls home when trying to restore a device.  If the device is eligible for a more recent iOS, iTunes and XCode 4.5 force you to upgrade the iOS.

In my case, I have an iPhone 4 that I want to test with iOS 5.1.1.  I have the .ipsw file that actually was used on this device.  iTunes generates an "not eligible" error when I try and force the restore from this .ipsw.  XCode 4.5 does also.  My understanding is that Apple is no longer signing 5.1.1 and my device is eligible for iOS 6, the reason for the error.

In the past, I had enough devices laying around that I shelved and used for testing.  I don't have that luxury now.

Two questions:
1. Is there any way to install an older iOS on device that is eligible for a newer iOS?
2. How are you testing on older iOS versions?

I welcome suggestions

Comment: I'd say no because if you're asking this, you probably don't even know what SHSH files are and why you should have saved them (which would essentially permit you to hack back an older firmware to a device).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot install an older iOS unless you are jailbroken and your SHSH blobs were stored with Cydia or TinyUmbrella.

Most people use the simulator, or older devices.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

can be used to find old xcodes and ios SDKs.

Comment: Also, FWIW, not alot of things become deal breakers within major versions. But things do get deprecated between Major versions. So i see your concern with 6 vs 5, alot of devices are still on 5. But for the most part things that you cannot test in simulator haven't changed such as the camera API. They just add some new syntax.

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer.  Seems premature to abandon device testing on iOS 5.  However, all of my devices were forced to update for one reason or other and I no longer have one.  Marching on...